# Algorithm for Reconstructing Point Sites from a Voronoi Diagram

Tags: reference-request, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

how can one construct a finite set of points in the euclidean plane from its Voronoi Diagram and, what is the complexity of the problem?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.5550, see references there

Comment: @MoritzFirsching that solves my problem! If you could turn that into an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a well studied problem and there are a couple of algorithms, for example using linear programming. For an overview take a recent reference, for example:

[Fitting Voronoi Diagrams to Planar Tesselations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.5550) by Greg Aloupis, Hebert Pérez-Rosés, Guillermo Pineda-Villavicencio, Perouz Taslakian, Dannier Trinchet

Answer (score 2):

See also:

> Biedl, Therese, Martin Held, and Stefan Huber. "Recognizing straight skeletons and Voronoi diagrams and reconstructing their input." In *Voronoi Diagrams in Science and Engineering* (ISVD), 2013 10th International Symposium on, pp. 37-46. IEEE, 2013.
>   ([IEEE link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6605976/).)

---

[image]

          

<sup>(Image from [Stefan Huber](https://www.sthu.org/research/publications/files/isvd2013-slides.pdf).)</sup>

---